# Что делает данный RewriteRule в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) ./?%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Здравствуйте, если не трудно, можете объяснить на пальцах, что делает последняя строчка? Каким образом она преобразовывает запрос?